# "sort result" of a php formula in a query

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following query and I would like to sort the results of the math formula  "echo "" . ((-$row["startweight"] + $row["currweight"])/$row["startweight"]) . " ";" which creates a percentage answer.  As there are many people in the result, I'd like to be able to sort the result of the formula in descending order highest to lowest.  I've spent a considerable amount of time researching this and I get the feeling it needs to be in some sort of array.  I hope not.   Here is the entire query for context purposes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo "<table border=1>
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Start Weight</th>
       <th>Current Weight</th>
       <th>Weight Diff</th>
       <th>Percent Diff</th>
       <th>Goal Weight</th>
       <th>Lbs2Go</th>
   <tr>";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["startweight"] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["currweight"] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . ($row["startweight"] - $row["currweight"]) . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . ((-$row["startweight"] + $row["currweight"])/$row["startweight"]) . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["goalweight"] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . ($row["currweight"] - $row["goalweight"]) . " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Thanks for your help.  (and yes... I'm an FNG to programming)

Answer (score 1):

you can sort in SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members order by (currweight-startweight)/startweight desc";
```

consider what you will get if startweight is 0

Comment: Thank you.  Fortunately the startweight can't ever be 0.  This sort works, however, I'm not sure how to see the actual percent.  I've tried creating a new variable to store it, but it seems a little more advanced than my current skill level.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @BrianK what is actual percent? where do you want to see it? maybe it make sense to read documentation?

Comment: I apologize.  I don't understand your question.  When you invoke the formula above, the resulting number is expressed in a percent i.e. 2.9874665 or similar. I'd also like to round that down to two decimal places or 2.99

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query to:

```
select * FROM members order by (currweight-startweight)/startweight
```

Comment: Thank you.  It appears your answer is the same as above.

Comment: Yes. Although I posted this answer first. You can check the timestamp - they are also the same!

Comment: My mistake. Please accept my apology.  This is my first time using this site.